# Is the following scheme real?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

**Nuclear fusion in a liquid Electrolytic Environment**

> The main necessary to consider the formula of the nuclear reaction, the following
>
> [image]
>
> This is the nucleus of the helium fusion reactions nuclei of deuterium and tritium reagents.

1. The occurrence of fusion reactions caused by the convergence of nuclear-reagents sufficient for this distance. Currently, the main funded, research in the field of physics focused attention and efforts on the way to improve the ambient temperature in which the reaction should occur. That, in the conventional logic, should lead to increase the speed with which the cores collide, which in turn would increase the probability of collision of nuclei reacting components.
2. For further discussion, we need to understand the following.
   A probabilistic approach, in itself, is very fruitful in the consideration of multiple environments, from microscopic objects in particular! In this case, you have to expect that, even at room temperature NFEE reactions (nuclear fusion) take place to be, but extremely improbable quantities. Therefore, our tasks are moving to the problem of increasing the collision probability of the process of nuclear components!
3. This is tremendously important conclusion, because on the basis of this decision offers NFEE problems.
   Create an electrolytic environment with directional movement of ions so. to deuterium and tritium nuclei move toward each other.
   The anions form the atoms of deuterium, suppose cations with the presence of tritium atoms.

   [image]

   The anions form the atoms of deuterium, suppose cations with the presence of tritium atoms. Then, when the electric current counter-movement of ions provoke a huge increase in the probability of a collision of nuclei reagent 12 H and 13H, and this, will lead to a very strong reaction activation NFEE.

Comment: Isn't this just cold fusion?  In which case no, it does not work.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Absolutely does not work. And you are ignoring lots of obvious issues. Like, why will the anions be deuterium and the cations tritium - remember they are very similar chemically? Where are you getting 12H or 13H (or perhaps just typos)? Why do you think particle velocity will get large in a liquid environment (lots of scattering)?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations that no one knows without defining them.   (NFEE,  TYAS)

Comment: This solution enhances the probability of convergence of the reactants, because the probability is always there!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not real.

The energies involved in electrolytic chemical reactions are typically on the scale of a few [electron-volts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt).  (This is why chemical batteries have a potential difference of a few volts per cell: each participant in the interaction exchanges typically one electron, and an energy cost of a few eV.)

The energy barrier which prevents two nuclei from having substantial overlap is many millions of electron-volts.  Furthermore, even if you can *get* the nuclei to overlap, the probability of fusion is also relatively low.

No chemical process can overcome this fundamental mismatch between energy scales.

To give you a hand-wavy idea of the processes involved, you might consider [antiprotonic helium](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v475/n7357/full/nature10260.html), or $\rm\bar p\ He^+$.  There (unlike with your fusion process) the cross-section for the antiproton to annihilate on the helium nucleus is *enormous*.  However the chemistry of this "molecule" conspires to keep the proton away from the nucleus, so that its lifetime is measured in microseconds.  You get a similar result with [protonium](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3193): it takes about a microsecond for the proton and antiproton to find each other and annihilate, even though they desperately want to.  You simply can't get two same-charge nuclei to fuse with each other by chemical reactions --- the energy isn't there.

This type of reaction, if were allowed, would be called a "cold fusion" reaction.
You may or may not know that the field of cold fusion has a somewhat troubled history.